# Rails Heroku Issue: status=500 for path=/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to deploy a more or less blank Rails app to Heroku, but I keep getting the "We're sorry but something went wrong" message..

The only error-ish line in the Heroku logs is this:

```
2013-01-11T19:30:59+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=murmuring-sierra-7952.herokuapp.com fwd=2.111.66.39 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=3ms service=718ms status=500 bytes=643
```

I understand this as heroku not being able to fetch the root path..

The only thing I have done apart from creating the app is to generate a controller, blogs, with index, show, new etc. and replace the root in my routes.rb as such:

```
resources :blogs
root :to => "blogs#index"
```

and i even added

```
match '/' => "blogs#index"
```

to make sure that "/" actually points to blogs#index

It all works fine on localhost, btw

Thanks, Viggo

Comment: Have you run the migrations on heroku? `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Yes. I tried out both rake db:reset and db:migrate, as well as bundle install on heroku.. But should rake db:migrate make a difference when i dont have any models?

Comment: Btw: I had the issue while deploying. It wouldn't recognize the sqlite3 gem, so I added a "group :development, :test do" tag around the "gem 'sqlite3'" line in my gemfile, which I got from another post.. Sorry, I totally forgot to mention that..

Comment: Then it's because of the database you're using :) See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku doesn't work with sqlite3, it works with postgresql.

You should have the following inside your gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Then run

```
$ bundle install
$ git push heroku master
```

You will find more information in heroku's own section on how to [get started](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3#write-your-app).

Comment: Where? On heruko or locally?

Comment: Locally.. I read somewhere that I could omit the pg include, because that would be handled by heroku, and I have been able to push it. Now i just get the "We're sorry something went wrong" message.. It turns out it works with the original index.html

Comment: Okay, I got it.. I had to install postgreSQL on my local machine in order for it to bundle install with the pg gem. Thanks a lot